# How do I set my ul's margin after setting every padding and margin to zero in CSS?

Tags: css, html, styling

This is the excerpt from my HTML code which I think is relevant:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css>
            * {
               padding: 0px;
               margin: 0px;
              }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The thing is, the li does not get a margin no matter what tricks I try in my knowledge.

What do I do?

Comment: So you removed the margin and padding on every element in your page and you're asking how to give the list items back a margin?

Comment: You do not load the CSS in your HTML code... Your example is 'too' minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

will set those respective properties to 10px each.  right now they are set to 0px, and for every element in the document, which is probably not what you want

Comment: I have tried that, but it does not work.

Comment: did you try it without `* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px }`?

Comment: I can't risk it. The website's design and layout depends on it, though I'll try it out.

Comment: try doing `li {margin: 10px !important; padding: 10px !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a positive margin anyway.

use:

```
li {
margin: 10px;
}
```

Change margin amount to what ever you need

Answer (score 0):

You should set the display to block in css like this:

```
ul li{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I hadn't tried that out, but sadly it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the styles for li BEFORE or AFTER the styles that eliminate all the margins and paddings?

putting ur li styles after should overwite the previous styles. And if you really must, try inline styles.

Oh, and you need to close your type="text/css. Its missing a ' " ' after the word css.